# gulp-load-plugins.sourcemaps.init() TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined

Tags: javascript, gulp, source-maps, gulp-load-plugins

I'm trying to adapt a gulp file to my purposes and I'm running into issues.  I only care about one task:

```
    gulp.task('js:browser', function () {
      return mergeStream.apply(null,
        Object.keys(jsBundles).map(function(key) {
          return bundle(jsBundles[key], key);
        })
      );
    });
```

It is using browserify to condense my bundle into a usable single file.  It uses these two methods and this object:

```
function createBundle(src) {
  //if the source is not an array, make it one
  if (!src.push) {
    src = [src];
  }


  var customOpts = {
    entries: src,
    debug: true
  };
  var opts = assign({}, watchify.args, customOpts);
  var b = watchify(browserify(opts));

  b.transform(babelify.configure({
    stage: 1
  }));

  b.transform(hbsfy);
  b.on('log', plugins.util.log);
  return b;
}

function bundle(b, outputPath) {
  var splitPath = outputPath.split('/');
  var outputFile = splitPath[splitPath.length - 1];
  var outputDir = splitPath.slice(0, -1).join('/');

  console.log(outputFile);
  console.log(plugins);
  return b.bundle()
    // log errors if they happen
    .on('error', plugins.util.log.bind(plugins.util, 'Browserify Error'))
    .pipe(source(outputFile))
    // optional, remove if you don't need to buffer file contents
    .pipe(buffer())
    // optional, remove if you dont want sourcemaps
    .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true})) // loads map from browserify file
       // Add transformation tasks to the pipeline here.
    .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write('./')) // writes .map file
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/public/' + outputDir));
}

var jsBundles = {
  'js/polyfills/promise.js': createBundle('./public/js/polyfills/promise.js'),
  'js/polyfills/url.js': createBundle('./public/js/polyfills/url.js'),
  'js/settings.js': createBundle('./public/js/settings/index.js'),
  'js/main.js': createBundle('./public/js/main/index.js'),
  'js/remote-executor.js': createBundle('./public/js/remote-executor/index.js'),
  'js/idb-test.js': createBundle('./public/js/idb-test/index.js'),
  'sw.js': createBundle(['./public/js/sw/index.js', './public/js/sw/preroll/index.js'])
};
```

When I run the gulp task js:bower I get the following error coming from the the `.pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))` expression:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined
```

I know that the lines are optional and I can just comment them out, but I do want them.  When I run the code in the example file it works properly, when I run it in my gulp file it gives me the error.  Any suggestions on what I might be missing?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`gulp-load-plugins` analyzes the contents of your `package.json` file to find out which Gulp plugins you have installed. Make sure that `gulp-sourcemaps` is among the `"devDependencies"` defined there. If not run

```
npm install --save-dev gulp-sourcemaps
```

There's a small chance that your problem is related to lazy loading the sourcemaps plugin. If the above doesn't help try requiring `gulp-load-plugins` like this:

```
var plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')({lazy:false});
```